# Download pics from URLs stored in array?

Tags: javascript, html, image, download

I am trying to download images I have displayed on my react app.  The app gets images from an API and displays them on the web page and also stores the img src in an array. I'm trying to make a download button that will loop through my src array and download all images displayed and need some guidance.  I have read many previous posts and realized I am not able to use cURL within my react app and the fetch API does not download the images. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this with JavaScript or is there a simple alternative with another programming language.

```js
const downloadAll = () => {
        const imgArr = document.querySelectorAll('img');
        for (let i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
            let a = imgArr[i].src;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `download` attribute of an anchor should do the trick...

EDIT

> download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Since this is not your case, you will have to create a blob with each image and fortunately, that is easy with the `fetch` API.

```
const downloadAll = async () => {
  // Create and append a link
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  document.documentElement.append(link);

  const imgArr = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  for (let i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    await fetch(imgArr[i].src)
      .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
      .then(blob => {

        let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Set the download name and href
        link.setAttribute("download", `image_${i}.jpg`);
        link.href = objectURL;

        // Auto click the link
        link.click();
    })
  }
};
```

Tested on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZEXZOXY?editors=0010).

Comment: Thank you for you help, when I use this code it adds a <a> tag with the download attribute with the last image in imgArr and adds the image at the bottom of my photo grid but does not download any images.

Comment: lol! Did I seriously forgot one line here?!? I edited.

Comment: Okay, so I added the last line, link.click() and when I click the download button it navigates to the image src URL. Any thoughts?

Comment: I edited with a tested answer this time ;)

Comment: I am getting following error. `res.blob is not a function`. If I remove the function parenthesis after the blob then the downloaded file is corrupted / empty.

Comment: @SardarFaisal: I can't say... Just create your own question, including the context of your issue. Link my answer in your question, if  it helps detailing the steps you've done in attempt to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer:

1. Go to Chrome settings => chrome://settings/downloads
2. Turn off: "ask where to save before downloading" & set custom folder in there
3. Open de console and Code:

```
const urls = ['imgUrl1', 'imgUrl2', ....]

const fetchFile = async function(url) {
    const resp = await fetch(url)
    return resp.blob()
}

const exportFile = async function(file) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = await URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.setAttribute('download', '');
    a.click();
}


let index = 0
while (index < 10000000) {
    const file = await fetchFile(urls[index])
    exportFile(file)
    index++
}
```

4. Turn ON: "ask where to save before downloading"

Go!

Comment: If I'm already displaying the image in an <img> tag, then what am I fetching with the url? Is the browse fetching images twice? Once for the JSX and second when you try to download it?

Comment: your script is awesome and saved me a lot of time, I just corrected some typos